# textview to shift on another line if text is long

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout`,in that there is a `TextView`which has long text and I want to add `ImageButton` which will be right aligned.But if the text is long the image button comes on its top.

I want the text of textview should come to next line if it is long so that imagebutton should not come on top of it.

Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_seminar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEMINAR"
        android:textColor="#322865"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_seminarName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_seminar"
        android:text="Optimizing Supply Chain gsgsggdfg"
        android:textColor="#6E6E6E"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_register1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_seminarName"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_seminarName"
            android:background="@drawable/button_register"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: I'd set the ImageButton first. Then align the TextView to the left of it. This should "anchor" ImageButton and let the TextView be free of growing in height. Also, get rid of the **+** sign when referencing existing ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ImageButton `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and your textView

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use `maxWidth` property in textview,it will helpful

```
android:maxWidth="yourdp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the relative layout set this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_seminar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEMINAR"
        android:textColor="#322865"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_seminarName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_seminar"
            android:text="Optimizing Supply Chain gsgsggdfg  fddddddd dddddd dddddd"
            android:textColor="#6E6E6E"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="8" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_register1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_seminarName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_seminarName"
            android:background="@drawable/button_register"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

use weightSum and layout_weight to adjust..

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `android:layout_toRightOf` on imagebutton, user `android:layout_toLeftOf` in textview

remove this

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_seminarName"
```

add this in your textView tv_seminarName

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_register1"
```

add this in your imageView

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="15dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_seminar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEMINAR"
        android:textColor="#322865"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_seminarName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Optimizing Supply Chain gsgsggdfg"
        android:textColor="#6E6E6E"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_register1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_register"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```